# How to refer a jsp file in one .war location to another .war location?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a file located in the server

> one_public.war/include/public/custom.jsp

i have to refer this to a file located in

> one.war/web/index.jsp

I tried using like

> ../../one_public.war/include/public/custom.jsp

to refer the location from index.jsp but its not working. 
Any idea about what i did wrong or do i have to do it in different way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: i do't think so you can as do't know the requirements but highly you can try this `response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/anotherWar/custom.jsp");`

Comment: i don't think that it is possible.

Comment: Means you need to access that jsp throught network over http only. Not by relative path or something.